# I want to lookup a value in a A using the value/s in B (Worksheet 1) and return the values in A (Worksheet 1) to B (Worksheet 2)

Tags: excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz0hj.jpg)How can I find the Session ID of the following ENTRIES from WORKSHEET 1?
**Worksheet 1**
A             B
1 | Session Id | Entries  |
2 | ---------- | -------- |
3 | 12345      | 890, 456 |
4 | 67890      | 123      |
5 | 23456      | 234, 789 |

**Worksheet 2**
A             B
1 | Entries    | Session Id|
2 | ---------- | --------  |
3 | 123        |           |
4 | 234        |           |
5 | 456        |           |
6 | 789        |           |
7 | 890        |           |

I did not do anything yet.

Comment: I suggest you look at index() with match().

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to create a formula for this. Should it be combined INDEX and MATCH?

Comment: index(target_range,match(index_value,index_range,0))